# ¿Llamar a funciones o métodos sobrecargados implica un costo en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: delphi, sobrecarga, lenguaje-compilado

¿Hay algún costo adicional en tiempo de ejecución por llamar a métodos sobrecargados?

Pregunto esto específicamente para **Delphi**, en caso que la respuesta no sea la misma para todos los lenguajes compilados.

Pienso que no debiera implicar costos adicionales ya que debe resolverse en tiempo de compilación, pero nunca puedes estar seguro, ¿o si?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro que puedes estar seguro, porque está [documentado](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Overloading_Procedures_and_Functions). Es el compilador quién lo resuelve (en tiempo de compilación, claro), así que no hay ningún costo adicional asociado a llamar a funciones o métodos sobrecargados en Delphi.

He realizado un pequeño experimento para demostrarlo:

```
var
  j: Integer;
  st: string;

procedure DoNothing(i: Integer); overload;
begin
  j := i;
end;

procedure DoNothing(s: string); overload;
begin
  st := s;
end;

procedure DoNothingI(i: integer);
begin
  j := i;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  MaxIterations = 10000000;
var
  StartTick, EndTick: Cardinal;
  I: Integer;
begin
  StartTick := GetTickCount;
  for I := 0 to MaxIterations - 1 do
    DoNothing(I);
  EndTick := GetTickCount;
  Label1.Caption := Format('Overlaod ellapsed ticks: %d [j:%d]', [EndTick - StartTick, j]);
  StartTick := GetTickCount;
  for I := 0 to MaxIterations - 1 do
    DoNothingI(I);
  EndTick := GetTickCount;
  Label1.Caption := Format('%s'#13'Normal ellapsed ticks: %d [j:%d]', [Label1.Caption, EndTick - StartTick, j]);
end;
```

Resultado: Casi todas las veces toma 31 *ticks* (milisegundos) para ambos en mi máquina de desarrollo, algunas veces toma solo 16 *ticks*.

[image: tiempo de ejecución de 31 ms.]